# Proving a variant of Parseval identity

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $f$ be a Schwartz function on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then, it is said that
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{(2\pi i)^{n/2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \widetilde{f}(y) e^{\frac{i}{2} \lVert y \rVert^2}dy=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x) e^{-\frac{i}{2} \lVert x \rVert^2}dx
\end{equation}
holds where $\widetilde{f}(y)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{ix \cdot y}f(x) dx$.

Also it seems to be called a sort of Parseval identity and translation-invariant. My question is

1. How does one prove the above equality?
2. Why is it called a variation of Parseval identity?
3. What does it mean by "translation-invariant"?

Could anyone please explain?

Comment: To prove, use Parseval. Remember that Parseval says that the integral of the product of 2 functions is equal, up to a factor, to the integral of their Fourier transforms. Take $f$ for one of the functions, and the Gaussian for the other one.

Comment: Product of two functions? Not convolution?

Comment: Product. It's saying that the inner product of 2 functions in $L^2$ is equal to the inner product of their Fourier transforms. More specifically, it's the Plancherel theorem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plancherel_theorem

Comment: But the equality does not exhibit any Gaussian function. How can we get rid of the Gaussian? Also, could you explain in what sense it is translation-invariant?

Comment: You apply Plancherel with one of the functions being a Gaussian. Since the Fourier transform of a Gaussian is another Gaussian it should give you the desired identity. BTW, I think there's a typo in your post, it should be a Gaussian in each integral (right now the first integral is missing a minus sign in the exponential).

Comment: No, the formula is copied directly from a book on Fresnel integral. It must be correct. By Gaussian, you mean $e^{-x^2}$?

Comment: Oh, it's an 'i', not a '1' in the exponentials?... OK, maybe I need some glasses.

Comment: I think what I wrote still holds by replacing the Gaussian with the Chirp function. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Square-integrable_functions,_one-dimensional

Comment: For $n=1$, the Fourier transform of $e^{-ix^p}$ is computed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4232100/121671)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's use the following convention (easier to work with) for the Fourier transform:
$$\widehat f(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb R^n}e^{-2i\pi\langle \xi, x\rangle}dx\tag{1}$$

Now, define $g(x)=e^{\frac i 2 \|x\|^2}$ to be the multidimensional chirp (Fresnel) function. This function is a tempered distribution and has a Fourier transform. Given a schwarz function $f$:

$$\int_{\mathbb R^n} f(x)\widehat g(x)dx=\int_{\mathbb R^n} \widehat f(y)g(y)dy\tag{2}$$

Fortunately, the (multidimensional) Fourier transform of $g$  comes down to the 1-dimensional case:
$$\int_{\mathbb R^n} e^{-2i\pi \langle \xi, x\rangle} e^{\frac i 2 \|x\|^2}dx = \left ( \int_{\mathbb R} e^{-2i\pi \xi_1 x_1} e^{\frac i 2 x_1^2}dx_1\right)\dots\left ( \int_{\mathbb R} e^{-2i\pi \xi_n x_n} e^{\frac i 2 x_n^2}dx_n\right)=\widehat h(\xi_1)\dots \widehat h(\xi_n)\tag{2}$$
where $h(t)=e^{\frac i 2 t^2}$ is the 1-dimensional chirp function.

To compute the 1-dimensional Fourier transform, note that $h^\prime(t)=ith(t)$.

Taking the Fourier transform, and using its properties,  gives the following differential equation:

$$2i\pi s\widehat h^\prime(s)=i \frac i {2\pi}\widehat h (s)$$
Solving this, and using the well-known Fresnel integral for the value of $h(0)$ gives
$$\widehat h(s)=\sqrt{2i\pi}e^{-2i\pi^2 s^2}$$
Plugging this back into $(2)$ gives the multi-dimensional Fourier transform:
$$ \widehat g(\xi) = \left (2i \pi\right)^{\frac n 2}e^{-2i\pi ^2\|\xi\|^2}$$

We can now go back to $(2)$:
$$(2i\pi)^{\frac n 2} \int_{\mathbb R^n} f(x) e^{-2i\pi^2\|x\|^2}dx=\int_{\mathbb R^n} \widehat f(y)e^{\frac i 2 \|y\|^2}dy$$

Using the fact that $\widetilde f(y)=\widehat f(-2\pi x)$, we obtain the desired result by change of variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete solution. The leave to the OP to argue why one can change the order of limit and integral in the last bit of my answer:

Using the definition of Fourer transform, polar coordinates, and Fubini's theorem we get
$$\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\widehat{f}(\mathbf{x}) e^{-i|\mathbf{x}|^2}\,d\mathbf{x}&=\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\int_{B(0;R)}\widehat{f}(\mathbf{x})\,e^{-\tfrac{i}{2}|\mathbf{x}|^2}\,d\mathbf{x}\\
&=\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\int^R_0\int_{\mathbb{S}_{n-1}}\widehat{f}(r\mathbf{u})e^{-\tfrac{i}{2}r^2}r^{n-1}\,\sigma_{n-1}(d\mathbf{u})\,dr\\
&=\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\int^R_0\int_{\mathbb{S}_{n-1}}\Big(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(\mathbf{t}) e^{-2\pi ir\mathbf{u}\cdot \mathbf{t}}e^{-\tfrac{i}{2}r^2}r^{n-1}\,d\mathbf{t}\Big)\,\sigma_{n-1}(d\mathbf{u})\,dr\\
&=\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(\mathbf{t})\int_{\mathbb{S}_{n-1}}\Big(\int^R_0e^{-2\pi ir\mathbf{u}\cdot \mathbf{t}}e^{-\tfrac{i}{2}r^2}r^{n-1}\,dr\Big)\,\sigma_{n-1}(d\mathbf{u})\,d\mathbf{t}\\
&=\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(\mathbf{t})\Big(\int_{B(0;R)}e^{-2\pi i\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{t}}e^{-\tfrac{i}{2}|\mathbf{x}|^2}\,d\mathbf{x}\Big)\,d\mathbf{t}\\
&=\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(\mathbf{t})\,e^{i2\pi^2|\mathbf{t}|^2}\Big(\int_{B(0;R)}e^{-\tfrac{i}{2}|\mathbf{x}+2\pi\mathbf{t}|^2}\,d\mathbf{x}\Big)\,d\mathbf{t}
\end{align}$$

It remains to argue that

1. The order of limit and the integral can be changed:
   $$\begin{align}
   \lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(\mathbf{t})&\,e^{i2\pi^2|\mathbf{t}|^2}\Big(\int_{B(0;R)}e^{-\tfrac{i}{2}|\mathbf{x}+2\pi\mathbf{t}|^2}\,d\mathbf{x}\Big)\,d\mathbf{t}\\
   &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(\mathbf{t})e^{i2\pi^2|\mathbf{t}|^2}\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\Big(\int_{B(0;R)}e^{-\tfrac{i}{2}|\mathbf{x}+2\pi\mathbf{t}|^2}\,d\mathbf{x}\Big)\,d\mathbf{t}
   \end{align}
   $$
2. That $\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\int_{B(0;R)}e^{-\tfrac{i}{2}|\mathbf{x}+2\pi\mathbf{t}|^2}\,d\mathbf{x}=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{-\tfrac{i}{2}|\mathbf{x}|^2}\,d\mathbf{x}$ exists.

---

The integral
$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{-\tfrac{1}{2}|\mathbf{x}|^2}\,d\mathbf{x}=2^{n/2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{-i|\mathbf{x}|^2}\,d\mathbf{x}$
is of course interpreted as a proper Riemann integral:
$$\begin{align}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{-|\mathbf{x}|^2}\,d\mathbf{x}&=\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\int_{[-R,R]^n}e^{-i|\mathbf{x}|^2}\,d\mathbf{x}\\
&=\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\Big(2\int^\infty_0 e^{-ix^2}\,dx\Big)^n\\
&=\Big(2\Gamma(3/2)e^{\tfrac{-i\pi}{4}}\Big)^n=\pi^{n/2}e^{-in\pi/4}
\end{align}$$
Hence, provided that the OP justifies (1) (some assumptions may be needed, for example $f\in L_1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is such that $\widehat{f}\in L_1(\mathbb{R}^n)$) we have that
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\widehat{f}(\mathbf{x})e^{-i|\mathbf{x}|^2}\,d\mathbf{x}=(2\pi)^{n/2}e^{-ni\pi/4}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(\mathbf{t})e^{i2\pi^2|\mathbf{t}|^2}\,d\mathbf{t}
$$

Comment: Could you tell me where $(2\pi i)^{-n/2}$ is?

Comment: That is more of a convention. For many analysis's, the Fourier transform  of a function $f$ is defined as $\widehat{f}(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{-2\pi ix\cdot \xi}f(x)\,dx$; other analysists define it as $\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{-ix\xi}f(x)\,dx$. With regards to the factor $i$ in $(2\pi i)^{n/2}$, I suspect that it may appear is the Fresnel type integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{-i |x|^2}\,dx$.  In $n=1$ for instance $\int^\infty_0e^{-ix^2}\,dt=\frac{3/2}e^{I\pi/4}$