# Fourier transform of $\cos(2\pi t^2)$

Tags: fourier-transform

I want to compute the fourier transform of the function $\cos(2πt^2)$

But when faced to this integral :
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cos(2\pi t^2)e^{-i2πft}dt = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{e^{i2πt^2}+e^{-i2πt^2}}2e^{-i2πft}dt
$$

I don't see how reducing $e^{i2πt^2}e^{-i2πft}$ to $e^{i2πt^2-i2πft}$ helps in solving the integral since we still don't have something factored by t. I think i'm missing a step in my reasoning.

Thanks

Comment: The function is not in $L^1$, nor $L^2$, so its Fourier transform cannot be directly computed by the usual integral. But that's ok, if you know a larger scope for FT, etc. What is your context, then?

Comment: My only indication for this problem is the allowed use of the following integral result : $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{j2πx^2}  \ dx =  1/2 (1+j)$. Hence why i went with the usual Fourier integral. Otherwise i don't see where i will be using it.

Comment: The integral in your indication is computed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2820135/121671)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this kind of indication, I suppose you are just expected to complete the square. For example for one of the two terms it gives
$$
\int e^{-2i\pi t^2}\,e^{-2i\pi xt}\,\mathrm d t = e^{i\pi x^2/2}\int e^{-2i\pi (t+x/2)^2}\mathrm d t = e^{i\pi x^2/2}\int e^{-2i\pi t^2}\mathrm d t = \frac{e^{i\pi x^2/2}}{2\,(1+i)}.
$$